# Presentation app with different UIView subclasses and XIB files

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I am making a presentations app with that contains 50 slides. Each slide can contain buttons,videos,...

So I was thinking about doing it this way. I create 50 classes that are subclasses from `UIView` with each their own xib file. With this I can put different buttons on the `UIView` and use `delegate methods` to handle them.

Then I have one `MainViewController` with an header and footer image and in the middle one `scrollView`. I load up the XIB files like this.

```
  UIView *rootView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"page1" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Put all these `UIViews` in an `NSArray` and next place them inside a `scrollView` by looping the `NSArray`

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrViews.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *view = [arrViews objectAtIndex:i];
    [view setFrame:frame];

[self.scrollView addSubview:view];
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * arrViews.count,scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

So I have the following `classes`:

```
Page1.h (subclassed from UIVIew)
Page1.m 
MainViewController.h (subclassed from UIViewController)
MainViewController.m
```

What my question is now, how can I say that the `UIViews` that I created (UIView *rootView) should use the classes of Page1.

Comment: Is this a one off thing, or might you ever want to create a different 'presentation'?

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard you have to change a `Class` to a custom class. So for example in your page1 XIB you have to go to Identity Inspector (3th tab) and in Class text box type Page1, and for next page you have to do it again. In that case you can call rootView like:

```
Page1 *rootView = (Page1*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"page1" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Hope this help.